# Ionic 3 custom icons

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Can I just add svg icons in the directory `/assets/myIcon.svg` and just call the icons as imgs:

```
<img src="assets/myIcon.svg" >
```

Also, I am trying to use icons from flaticon. Where should I save the license (a pdf file)?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use custom icon in your app, here is a solution that worked great for me.

1. Put your .svg icon file(s) in:

   /src/assets/icons/...
2. In your app.scss file, add this scss code:

```css
ion-icon {
    &[class*="prefix-"] {
        mask-size: contain;
        mask-position: 50% 50%;
        mask-repeat: no-repeat;
        background: currentColor;
        width: 1em;
        height: 1em;
    }
    // custom icons
    &[class*="prefix-categories"] {
        mask-image: url(../assets/icon/ic_categories.svg);
    }
    &[class*="prefix-menu"] {
        mask-image: url(../assets/icon/ic_menu.svg);
    }
}
```

3. Call it in your .html file:

```html
<ion-icon name="prefix-menu"></ion-icon>
```

4. To apply more style to the custom icon, you can write something like:

```css
ion-icon.ion-ios-prefix-categories {
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Hope this helps. Anyway about the licensing, I don't know.